# MeasurementFormatter naturalScale not showing centimeters

Tags: ios, swift

I'm setting up a MeasurementFormatter object, using .naturalScale for the unitOptions and locale to Canada for metric output. For some reason, it is completely skipping centimeters when generating strings.

Here is code you can paste into a playground:

```
import UIKit

let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "EN_CA")
formatter.unitOptions = .naturalScale

formatter.string(from: Measurement(value: 2, unit: UnitLength.centimeters))
```

The output here is `"0.02 m"` rather than the expected `"2 cm"`.

Other examples:

```
formatter.string(from: Measurement(value: 0.2, unit: UnitLength.centimeters))
formatter.string(from: Measurement(value: 0.1, unit: UnitLength.centimeters))
```

This outputs `"0.002 m"` and then `"1 mm"`, entirely skipping cm.

Any thoughts on why its skipping centimeters? Does it have something to do with the locale? Is it something else? Just a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: What output do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: The above is giving output of "0.02m". Expect it to output just "2cm". Going to edit and update the question.

Comment: Try `formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit`

Comment: I do want the functionality of .naturalScale, though, with it adapting numbers to the closest appropriate unit. If it turns out there is no way of getting it to display cm, then I will probably end up going with .providedUnit, but its not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. It's a bit cumbersome, but it works.

```
struct DistanceCm {

    init(_ distanceCm: Double) {
        distance = distanceCm
    }

    let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()

    var _distance: Double?
    var distance: Double {

        get {
            return _distance!
        }

        set {
            _distance = newValue
            formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "EN_CA")

            if (newValue >= 1 && newValue < 100) {
                formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
            } else {
                formatter.unitOptions = .naturalScale
            }
        }
    }


    func toString() -> String {
        return formatter.string(from: Measurement(value: _distance!, unit: UnitLength.centimeters))
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let d1 = DistanceCm(0.1)
    print("\(d1.toString())")

    let d2 = DistanceCm(2.0)
    print("\(d2.toString())")

    let d3 = DistanceCm(200.0)
    print("\(d3.toString())")

    let d4 = DistanceCm(20000.0)
    print("\(d4.toString())")

    let d5 = DistanceCm(200000.0)
    print("\(d5.toString())")
}
```

Output is:

```
1 mm
2 cm
2 m
200 m
2 km
```

p.s. I'm guessing that the formatter ignores 'cm' because it's not a multiple of 10^3. SI units generally go up or down in multiples of 1000.

Comment: That makes sense, I suppose. Interesting. Thanks for taking the time to put that example together!